# I want to add an element to array after matching pattern found using perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I've copied all lines of a file to an array and looping this array for pattern matching once pattern matches, I want to add lines to same array and print in another file.

```
my @lines = <FILE_IN>;
foreach my $line (@lines){
if($line =~m/\s(\w*)_region\s/){
print $line;
}
```

I tried till pattern matching, and want to add an element after this search.

Comment: my @lines =<FILE_IN>; foreach my $index (reverse 0..$#lines){ if ($lines[$index]=~m/\s(\w*)_region\s){ splice @lines($index,0,"/t$string\n");} } this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $ifile,'<:encoding(UTF-8)', '/path/to/file.txt' || die $!;
while (my $line = <$ifile>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~m/\s(\w*)_region\s/x) {
        print $line
    }   
}
close $ifile;
```

Comment: Please consider adding some description. How this code will solve the problem.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.